# Sort array by distance from current location

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array by the distance from the current location. Below first of all you see the `organizationObject`, which contain different values and then we have locations which is an array of different locations. the reason why it is an `array` is because an organization can have multiple locations. Then in my ViewController i'm creating a set of test objects and appending to an array. My question is how i can sort this `orgArray` according to the distanceFromLocation? If there is multiple locations in the location array, it should take the closest one.

**OrganizationObject**

```
class OrganizationObject {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var image: UIImage
    var locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
    init(id: Int, name: String, image: UIImage, locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.locations = locations
    }

}
```

**Appending test objects to array. In viewDidLoad**

```
orgArray.append(OrganizationObject(id: 0, name: "Statens Museum For Kunst", image: UIImage(named: "statensmuseum.jpg")!, locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.6888127, longitude: 12.578330300000061)]))
orgArray.append(OrganizationObject(id: 0, name: "7 eleven", image: UIImage(named: "7eleven.jpg")!, locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.334682, longitude: 8.231820900000002)]))
orgArray.append(OrganizationObject(id: 0, name: "Kongens have", image: UIImage(named: "kongenshave.jpg")!, locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.6852905, longitude:12.579845200000022)]))
orgArray.append(OrganizationObject(id: 0, name: "Magasin du nord", image: UIImage(named: "magasin.jpg")!, locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.6456604, longitude: 3.053486600000042), CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.7835017, longitude: 12.370985799999971)]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution. It's a little more complicated that a straightforward call to a sort function for a couple of reasons: firstly the need to find the closest location for the organization, as mentioned in the question, and secondly the fact that the haversine calculation used inside `CLLocation`'s `distanceFromLocation:` method can slow things down if used naively.

For those reasons I've created a special object to do the sort, so that I can use a member dictionary to [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the results of calls to `distanceFromLocation`. This won't make a difference for the test data, but will matter if you ever need to deal with a large set of places.

As a side note - it might make things a bit simpler if `OrganizationObject` stored a `CLLocation` and not a `CLLocationCoordinate` - though this is a fairly minor issue.

Here's the code:

```
class OrganizationSorter {

  var memoizedValues = [Int:CLLocationDistance]()

  private func shortestDistanceToOrganizationFromLocation(organization:OrganizationObject,location:CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance? {

    let memoizedValue = memoizedValues[organization.id] //Check whether we've done this calculation before, if so return the result from last time
    if memoizedValue != nil {
        return memoizedValue
    }

    //There should probably be some code around here to check
    //that the organization object has at least one location
    //I'm assuming it does to simplify things

    var shortestDistance : CLLocationDistance? = nil
    let locations = organization.locations
    if locations.count > 0 {
      for coord in locations {
        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: coord.latitude, longitude: coord.longitude)
        let dist = loc.distanceFromLocation(location)

        if shortestDistance == nil || shortestDistance > dist {
          shortestDistance = dist
        }
      }
    }

    if shortestDistance != nil {
      memoizedValues[organization.id] = shortestDistance
    }

    return shortestDistance
  }

  func sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(orgArray:[OrganizationObject],location:CLLocation) -> [OrganizationObject] {
    let sortedArray = orgArray.sort { (a:OrganizationObject, b:OrganizationObject) -> Bool in
      let dist1 = self.shortestDistanceToOrganizationFromLocation(a, location: location)
      let dist2 = self.shortestDistanceToOrganizationFromLocation(b, location: location)
      return dist1 < dist2     
    }
    memoizedValues.removeAll() //reset memoized values in case object is used twice
    return sortedArray
  }
}
```

I've tested it on your example data, using the location of the Christiansborg Palace in Copenhagen as a test loc, and got the following ordering:

```
Kongens have
Statens Museum For Kunst
Magasin du nord
7 eleven
```

which seems to match up to the coordinates given - it looks like the nearest coords for Magasin du Nord are somewhere in a town on the outskirts of Copenhagen (the other one's in Lille?), and 7 eleven is in Sweden.

Here is how the class is used (using the test data from the original question, with the `id` values in the `OrganizationObject`s changed so they are not all 0 (otherwise the code will not work).

```
let location = CLLocation(latitude: 55.676251, longitude: 12.580570) //Christiansborg Palace, chosen since it is relatively near the other locations, to make it obvious whether results are sensible or not

let orgSorter = OrganizationSorter()

let sortedLocations = orgSorter.sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(orgArray, location: location)

for org in orgArray {
  print(org.name)
}

print("\n")

for org in sortedLocations {
  print(org.name)
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example on how to use this class? :)

Comment: ohh so this is in playground?

Comment: Just updated the answer with the test code I used - I didn't use a playground, just an empty project. Note that I changed your data so the ids of the orgs weren't all zero

Comment: Thank you yes there is some erros in the data, but this is just test data. thank you

Comment: hmm i've tested it and it returns the same order in both print? what could cause this

Comment: The memoization relies on the object ids being different. You need to change them so they are all different - if they are the same the memoization will cache the first org and return it for all calls to the method, so the sort won't work

Comment: ooh of course and beside that is there a easy way to ensure that all values is stored in sortedArray. right now it only seem to be able to return name

Comment: `sortedLocations` is an array of `OrganizationObject` - the loop is printing out the `name` but the whole object is there for each item

Comment: hmm i still seem to get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` sometime

Comment: Common causes 1. unconnected IBOutlets 2. UIImage(named) calls referring to images that don't exist, or with a small typo in the image name (maybe in the orgArray). Use the stack trace to find out where this is - should be simple

Comment: It means an implicitly unwrapped optional (one with !) is nil when it shouldn't be